# How to update/remove ffmpeg on Windows 10

Tags: python, cmd, ffmpeg

I found a python script that had to use `ffmpeg` via cmd.exe thus I "installed" ffmpeg following [these](http://adaptivesamples.com/how-to-install-ffmpeg-on-windows/) instructions. I downloaded the latest version ffmpeg 3.4.1 but would like to replace it with ver 2.4.x. (I think syntax from the .py file is for ver 2.4.x). I replaced the entire folder with files from the older version zip but when I input `ffmpeg -version` it still shows version 3.4.

I also tried removing path from environment variables,rebooting, and deleting entire ffmpeg folder to no avail. CMD.exe still displays ffmpeg as version 3.4 even when the entire folder is deleted. I was not able to find anything on ffmepg documentation or on google. I know its not exactly programming related but I thought I would get an answer here rather than in video production.

Snippet of the code

```
system("./ffmpeg -i xxx.ts -c copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc xxx.mp4")
```

Comment: I have a similar script in use. Does it point to a specific folder? Or will it just do something like subprocess.call('ffmpeg...') ?

Comment: A better place to put a question like this would be [Super User](https://superuser.com/).

Comment: Why downgrade from 3.4 to 2.4?

Comment: @BillBell I will try there next. Thanks